# AngularJS: $$selectors undefined when trying to use ngAnimate

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

This is driving me up the wall!  I am trying to use angular-animate.js but some reason the line $$selectors property of $$animateProvider (line 451) is undefined.  Can someone explain how this property gets populated?

This situation is causing the lookup function at line 617 to throw "TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined"

My js includes look like this:

```
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

CSS includes like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/animate-css/animate.css"/>
```

and my app.js like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    // Angular modules (dependencies)
    'ngRoute',          // routing
    'ngSanitize',       // sanitizes html bindings (ex: sidebar.js)
    'ngAnimate',        // animations
    'ui.bootstrap'      // ui-bootstrap (ex: carousel, pagination, dialog)
]);
```

The frustrating thing was that this *was* working but I've somehow broken it.  I've tried cleaning and downloading all the libraries again.  Any help greatfully received!

I am using Gulp and Bower to download/import.  All the files are present and being loaded by the browser:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined
at lookup (angular-animate.js:617)
at animationRunner (angular-animate.js:681)
at performAnimation (angular-animate.js:1284)
at angular-animate.js:959
at angular-animate.js:539
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15606)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15824)
at done (angular.js:10263)
at completeRequest (angular.js:10435)
at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10376)
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole console error ? How are you importing your dependencies ? Bower ? Manually ?

Comment: Add it in your question by editing, it will be more clear. It sounds like a library dependency trouble. Could you check that your version of angular and angular-animate match ? (By checking their bower.json files)

Comment: are you currently trying to use it in a directive or controller? and if so please post that code

Comment: The bower configuration states to use 1.3.15 for both angular and angular-animate. I've just manually examined the javascript files and found that angular file was at 1.4.0 bizarrely!  Having now changed the bower.json to use 1.4.0, the error has gone.  I can't figure out why one file would be later than another.  I assumed if i entered an exact version number, bower would download *only* that version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a version conflict with angular 1.4 and angular-material master, which depends on 1.3.

Probably updating your angular version "`"angular": ">=1.4.",`" in bower.json should solve this problem.

Comment: similar problems here... it didnt work TypeError: Cannot read property 'nav' of undefined
    at G (angular-animate.min.js:6)